# Solving wave equation on a disk with DSolve in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I want to obtain the general answer to the wave equation:

$$
u_{mn}(r, \theta, t) = [A\cos(c l_{mn} t) + B\sin(c l_{mn} t)]\ \mathrm J_m(l_{mn} r)\ [C\cos(m \theta) + D\sin(m \theta)]
$$

where $ \mathrm J_m $ and $ l_{mn} $ are Bessel related functions.

I want to solve it with `DSolve`. I can solve the $ r $ and $ t $ dependent part with `DSolve`, it works.

```
   drumEqu =D[uu[r, t], {t, 2}] - 1/r D[uu[r, t], {r, 1}]-D[uu[r, t], {r, 2}] == 0
   bc = uu[1, t] == 0;
   ic1 = uu[r, 0] == 0;
   ic2 = Derivative[0, 1][uu][r, 0] == 1;
   sol = DSolve[{drumEqu, bc, ic1, ic2}, uu[r, t], {r, t}]
```

If I add the $ \theta $, dependence it breaks.

```
    bc = u[1, theta,t] == 0;
    ic1 = u[r,theta, 0] == 0;
    ic2 = Derivative[0,0,1][u][r, theta, 0] == 1;
    CircMembEq = D[u[r, theta, t], {t, 2}] == (D[u[r, theta, t], {r, 2}] + 1/r D[u[r,theta, t], r] +1/r^2 D[u[r, theta, t], {theta, 2}]);
    DSolve[{CircMembEq, bc,ic1, ic2}, u[r, theta, t], {r, theta, t}]
```

Comment: That's a pretty big ask, and I doubt that MMa can handle it without you separating variables yourself and then having MMa satisfy the bc's.  In any case, for the` theta` dependent case, your bc and ic's are for `uu[r,t]` rather than `u[r, theta, t]`, and there are no conditions for `theta` at all.   You do not even specify `theta` to be single valued.  It has not been very long that MMa could even solve your first equation.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, it gives insights on possibilities and limitations of MMA regarding PDE. How would you specify that theta is single-valued?

Comment: Actually, your second problem that includes theta still has no angular dependence in the bc or ic's so the solution should be the same as your first problem.  MMa is still early in its solutions of pde's.  Version 10 can't even solve your first problem.  Maybe version 12 will do more.Specifying a single value theta is not always straightforward.  If you are starting with an expression as in your Latex expression above, specifying `m` as an integer does it.  Periodic bc and ic's will do it, but that is not always possible.  I'm not sure that MMa will accept `u[theta] = u[theta + 2 Pi]` yet.